# How can I navigate from a variable using webbrowser.navigate()?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I want to open a webpage from the webbrowser control. However, the address is not fully known:

```
string site = "page.php";
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.example.com/site");
```

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erm, not sure I understand your question but maybe this:

```
string site = "page.php";
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.example.com/" + site);
```